# How to tag address in China

Tags: openstreetmap, china

In China address is usually like: No.few homes, building number, which unit

or:

`No.23,Unit 2,Bldg.1 47th Yard, Fengchan Road Jinshui District`

Does OSM support this operation?

Comment: cross-post: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/56513/how-to-tag-address-in-china